# How to set up a bridge between two docker containers (connection refused)

Tags: docker, nginx, sails.js, bridge

Well I'm trying to set up a bridge between a static file (nginx) server and a dynamic content server.

Both dockers work correctly as a singular entity. However it seems the nginx server can't forward (reverse proxy) data to the dynamic content server.
It also works perfectly fine if I do not use dockers, but instead just run in the host operating system.

The dockers (containers named "sails" and "nginx") are connected with:

```
docker network create -d bridge --subnet 172.25.0.0/16 bink
docker network connect bink sails
docker network connect bink nginx
```

The nginx tries has a link to a proxy given by:

```
location /api {
    proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:1337;
}
```

This is the port the other docker listens to:   `http://127.0.0.1:1337/api/get-employees/` (example url) does give me correct data, when ran from the host os. (And when the docker is alive).

However `error.log` in the nginx server shows:

> 2018/03/22 15:21:12 [error] 8#8: *11 connect() failed (111: Connection
>   refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.25.0.1, server: _,
>   request: "GET /api/order-status-list/?_dc=1521732072867 HTTP/1.

I've also tried manually getting the data inside the nginx server (after `docker exec -it nginx sh`)

```
wget 127.0.0.1:1337/api/get-employees
wget: can't connect to remote host (127.0.0.1): Connection refused
```

---

Results of `docker network inspect bink`

```
[
    {
        "Name": "bink",
        "Id": "e859514bd4186a0cc7fa7b1021c05e99cbb1d6fcf903b024c63fad2c5880ec6a",
        "Created": "2018-03-22T16:06:58.373431562+01:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.25.0.0/16"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": false,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "1d96ac9b62dcce80d24552b8c9513e4d91f9c9fb6bc9ac731d2e635ba1ad0ac4": {
                "Name": "nginx",
                "EndpointID": "0429077af2cf0573ec073e9834fae7b710daf3c9d4e0f9bce7638ad9c4d07205",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:19:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.25.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "2ce6e54bf01c73ca06306b49a8021ab2b438710607a96a32f3c3349d89e93293": {
                "Name": "sails",
                "EndpointID": "98c5bece45cd77a468a8dc92c6938525bd8ef38d27051e675ae1c4494e5081b4",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:19:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.25.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {}
    }
]
```

everything seems to be as expected?

---

EDIT: I can get data from the sails/dynamic from the nginx docker by explicitly stating the ip adress of the sails docker:

```
wget 172.25.0.2:1337/api/get-employees
```

gives expected results. However this is not a solution as the internal ips of the docker networks should be a implementation detail and should not be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two containers have different IP addresses, one is `172.25.0.2` and another is `172.25.0.3`. That's why you cannot use `127.0.0.1` to access each other.

User-defined bridge provides automatic DNS resolution between containers. You can use container name to connect to a different container.

For more information, see https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#differences-between-user-defined-bridges-and-the-default-bridge

Comment: That would mean the setup for my development pc (which doesn't put the images in a container) is intrinsically different from the production environment? - and i have to modify the nginx config on the production manually each time? How is this typically done? Running both servers in the same container also seems to go against what docker tries to do.

Comment: Maybe you can bind-mount your development Nginx config to the container, without touching production Nginx config?

Comment: That would make the production nginx container dependent on a "specific" name for the other container. It doesn't make those two processes separate (testable) and "whoever might be listening to port 1337".